# How does an object within an ObservableCollection gets overwrited when adding another object within the Collection

Tags: c#, foreach, observablecollection

```
ObservableCollection<TypeA> TempList = ObservableCollection<TypeA>();
List<TypeB> FullValues =  listB;    
Count = intA;
foreach (var ListA in AllList)
{
    for (var i = 1; i < Count; i++)
    {
        ListA.Name = FullValues[i].Name;
        ListA.Surname = FullValues[i].Surname;
        ListA.Amount = FullValues[i].Amount;
        ListA.Address = FullValues[i].Address;
        ListA.Source = FullValues[i].Source;
        ListA.OrderCreationDate = FullValues[i].Date;
        ListA.Type = FullValues[i].Date;
        ListA.Commerce = FullValues[i].Commerce;
        TempList.Add(ListA);
    }
}
```

Hello, I'm using an `ObservableCollection` of a specific type to be filled by a local variable of the same type but using the Add method adds the new object and overwrites the preceding.
I need to add values to the same object but more than one time. So i am using an `ObservableCollection` to store the values more than time 
Tried with List and `ObservableCollection`

Expected Result: The list for example contains 3 values with
`ListA[0]`, `ListA[1]`, `ListA[2]`

Actual Result:
`ListA[2]`, `[2]`, `[2]`

Thank you for your help

Edited: I tried to add another case of the issue, this may look dumb but i need to duplicate the main object to add other values to them and keep them within the same list and as someone said, i am still using the same object thats why it is not changing:

```
List<string> RoadType = List<string>();
RoadType = somevalues;
foreach(var roads in listofroads)
{

roads.street = "xxxxx"
roads.country= "xxxxx"

//I want to duplicate roads twice

TestList.Add(roads);
TestList.Add(roads);


count = 0;
//Changing the properties of the object
foreach(var newroads in TestList)
{
roads.street = RoadType[i].street;
roads.country = RoadType[i].country;
count++
MainRoadList.Add(newroads);

}
MainRoadList.Add(roads);
}
```

Comment: You're adding the same `ListA` object multiple times to `TempList`. You change its properties every time, but it's *the same object*, so the properties will end up with whatever values you assign last. Don't do that. Create a new object `var newObj = new TypeA();` in your inner loop, then copy all those properties from `FullValues[i]` to `newObj`, then add `newObj` to TempList.

Comment: You are adding the same object `ListA` to the list 3 times, and changes its values between. `TempList` will contains `ListA` 3 times with the same values (because it is the same object) and the values will be these of the 3rd one (because that's your last assignment).

Comment: Actually it's even worse; `FullValues` is empty. This will just throw an exception. Can you show us an example that at least runs without crashing? Why are you looping through AllList but not actually using anything from AllList? This code seems very confused.

Comment: Please post sample code that we can copy/paste and run which illustrates the problem you're seeing (currently `TypeA`, `intA`, `AllList`, and `listB` are all undefined). But as others have pointed out, the `for` loop inside the `foreach` loop is iterating over the same instance of `ListA` each time.

Comment: The code actually runs Ed Plunkett. I edited the dummy code above.
I wont be able to post the full code as i am using MVVM model on a WPF application this, i will have to post a huge amount of code and confidential.
As You said on the first comment Ed Plunkett, it is actually the same object. I have a main object for the foreach and want to duplicate it and edit the properties within, but actually even using var newObj = new TypeA(); does not make it work

Comment: Added a new case